SQLite.Interop in Windows 11 - Arm64
Having issue with using SQLite database on Windows 11 based on ARM64 CPU.
It is returning an error:
Unable to load DLL "SQLite.Interop.dll" or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)\
Did a research and found that there is no official SQLite.Interop.dll for ARM64 Windows machines for now https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki, but it can be built somehow by our own.\
Tried to use the following approach proposed by rhubarb-geek-nz, but it doesn't build that native library for ARM64 despite the fact that what is written in the Readme. https://github.com/jhochwald/SQLite.Interop-win?tab=readme-ov-file \
In addition, tried to use the following approach from official SQLite, didn't work easier: https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.118.0/sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.118.0.zip
We should use only native ARM64 library. Cannot use either emulation or simulation mode on ARM machine to run application as x64 or x86.
Does anyone have any practical implementation of application on ARM64 Windows 11 machine with using SQLite databases?

Have you tried https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net, yet?

@Fildor I'm afraid that solution neither support ARM64 build.

"This version uses SQLitePCLRaw to provide platform independent versions of SQLite." - made me think it should. Did you try or is that an assumption?

@Fildor I did try to use SQLitePCLRaw package and with SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3, but id didn't generate ARM build as well.
